# Deriving the definition of stochastic integrals with respect to Ito processes from first principles

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

When I first encountered the definition of integrals with respect to Ito processes (Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance Vol II), I didn't think twice.  However, I wanted to see if the definition could be derived.

In the rest of this post $\bar{f}$ is such that $\bar{f}'=f$ and $t_{j}^{f}$ is such that $t_{j}\leq t_{j}^{f}\leq t_{j+1}$ according to the mean-value theorem, for some process $f$.

Consider the process
$$X(t)=X(0)+\int_{0}^{t}\Delta(u)\;dW(u)+\int_{0}^{t}\Theta(u)\;du$$
where the processes $\Theta_{t}(\omega)$ and $\Delta_{t}(\omega)$ are adapted to the Brownian motion $W_{t}(\omega)$.  Then if $\Gamma_{t}(\omega)$ is adapted to $X_{t}(\omega)$, we define
$$\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)\;dX(u)=\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)\Delta(u)\;dW(u)+\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)\Theta(u)\;du,$$
which is of course what we would expect by writing (formally)

$$\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)(\Delta(u)\;dW(u)+\Theta(u)\;du)=\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)\Delta(u)\;dW(u)+\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)\Theta(u)\;du.$$

**It seems this should be derivable (rather easily) from the original definition of the Ito stochastic integral.**  However, when I tried to do this, I failed:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)\;dX(u)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\left(\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}}\Delta(u)\;dW(u)+\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}}\Theta(u)\;du\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\cdot\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}}\Delta(u)\;dW(u)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\cdot\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}}\Theta(u)\;du\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\cdot\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}}\Delta(u)\;dW(u)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})(\bar{\Theta}(t_{j+1})-\bar{\Theta}(t_{j}))\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\cdot\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}}\Delta(u)\;dW(u)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\Theta(t_{j}^{\Theta})(t_{j+1}-t_{j})\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\cdot\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}}\Delta(u)\;dW(u)+\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)\Theta(u)\;du.
\end{align*}$$
where $t_{j}\leq t_{j}^{\Theta}\leq t_{j+1}$ and $\bar{\Theta}'=\Theta.$

At this point it would appear nothing can be done with the first sum since we don't have a mean-value theorem for Ito stochastic integrals (as quantified by Ito's lemma); i.e. there does not in general exist a $t_{j}^{\Delta}\in[t_{j},t_{j+1}]$ such that
$$\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}}\Delta(u)\;dW(u)=\Delta(t_{j}^{\Delta})(W(t_{j+1}-W(t_{j})).$$

And in any event it doesn't really matter, since even if we had this result, it would not be known a priori whether the resulting sum converges (or whether it converges to the correct stochastic integral) due to the sensitivity of the limiting sums with respect to the sampling point used.

To get a more concrete sense of the difficulty, consider the special case $\Delta(u)=f(W(u))$.

Then
$$\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}}\Delta(u)\;dW(u)=\bar{f}(W(t_{j+1}))-\bar{f}(W(t_{j}))-\frac{1}{2}\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}}f'(W(u))\;du,$$

and the first sum becomes
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\left(\bar{f}(W(t_{j+1}))-\bar{f}(W(t_{j}))-\frac{1}{2}\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}}f'(W(u))\;du\right)\\
\;\;\;\;=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\left(\bar{f}(W(t_{j+1}))-\bar{f}(W(t_{j}))\right)-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\left(\int_{t_{j}}^{t_{j+1}}f'(W(u))\;du\right)\\
\;\;\;\;=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})f(W(t_{j}^{f}))(W(t_{j+1})-W(t_{j}))-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})f'(W(t_{j}^{f'}))(t_{j+1}-t_{j})\\
\;\;\;\;=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\Delta(t_{j}^{f})(W(t_{j+1})-W(t_{j}))-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)f'(W(u))\;du.\end{array}
$$

Putting this together yields

$$\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)\;dX(u)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\Delta(t_{j}^{f})(W(t_{j+1})-W(t_{j}))-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)f'(W(u))\;du+\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)\Theta(u)\;du,$$
and it's hard to see how this ends up being equal to the original definition.

One would need to somehow show that the mean-value sampling $\Delta(t_{j}^{f})$ in the first sum results in

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j\in\Pi_{n}}\Gamma(t_{j})\Delta(t_{j}^{f})(W(t_{j+1})-W(t_{j}))=\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)\Delta(u)\;dW(u)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(u)f'(W(u))\;du.$$

And in any event, this is just a special case of the process $\Delta_{t}(\omega)$.

Comment: @ Taylor Martin : I am not sure to agree with the way you seem to define your stochastic integral with respect to $X$ (at least I don't consider this as a classical construction, maybe a result ca be build in this direction though). Moreover you shoud add conditions on $\Theta, \Delta, \Gamma$ processes for all this to make sense in the first place (unless you want to reason heuristically first). My advice is to start with elementary processes integrable with respect to $X$ then extend the result to more general process $\Gamma$. Best regards

Comment: Last remark I have read the "Ito's proof" in your blog but I think you have missed a detail, the convergence of the quadratic variation of Brownian motion to $T$ is true in probability over the set of all partition of time interval [0,T]. Otherwise the convergence is a.s. to $\infty$. To keep an almost sure CV you have to add the constraint of refining sequence of partitions (this is why stochastic integration need a probability measure and cannot be performed in an probabilistically independent way).You have to be cautious with the way you use limits. Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge - Regarding your first comment, please provide your definition if you disagree with mine; however, I am using the definition that is regularly encountered in mathematical finance texts.  Also, there really isn't any need to be pedantic here with the conditions of the coefficient processes; they are more or less implied and in any case you can just assume the ones regularly imposed: adadpability, $L^{2}(\Omega\times[0,t])$ integrable, and $\omega$-a.s. continuous as a function of $t$.

Comment: @TheBridge - Regarding your second comment, the convergence is true for each $t\geq0$ in $L^{p}(\Omega)$ ($1\leq p\leq2$) no matter how you construct the sequence of partitions $\Pi_{n}$ as long as $||\Pi_{n}||\to0$.  As is well known, you can construct a particular sequence $\Pi_{n}$ so that for a **fixed** $\omega$, $\text{QV}^{2}(W)(\omega)=\alpha$ for any $\alpha>0$ including $+\infty.$  However, you can avoid all of this by demanding that $||\Pi_{n}||\to0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}||\Pi||_{n}<\infty$; then by Borel-Cantelli the QV process does converge pathwise $\omega$-a.s. to $t$.

Comment: @TaylorMartin So why do you not follow TheBridge's hint? Prove the claim first for simple (aka elementary) processes and then extend it...